# Multiple yml files configuring in corresponding Configuration class (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml, configuration-files, properties-file

I have more than one yml files in Spring Boot in resource classpath location like following structure of Spring Boot. Initially I have written only for application-abc.yml and at the time all the values of this file was loading in their corresponding class but when I have added on another file application-xyz.yml then also it loads into their corresponding configuration classes but at this time only loading the values of application-xyz.yml in both the configuration classes. So, want help to configure values of both the files in their corresponding configuration files in a single build :

```
-src
  -main
     -java
        -packages
          -config
             -ApplicationAbcConfig.java
             -ApplicationConfig.java
             -ApplicationFactory.java
             -ApplicationXyzConfig.java
             -Authentication.java
             -Operations.java
             -Payload.java
             -RequestPayload.java
             -ResponsePayload.java

         -services
             -YmlConfigurationSelection.java

         -resources
            -application.yml
            -application-abc.yml
            -application-xyz.yml

         -MultipleYmlDemoProject.java
```

**Content of application-abc.yml**

```
authentication:
  name: name
  type: type
  payload:
    request:
      - sequence: 1
        attributes:
          - attributes1
          - attributes2
    response:
      - sequence: 1
        attributes:
          - attributes3
          - attributes4

operations:
  name: name
  type: type
  payload:
    request:
      - sequence: 1
        attributes:
          - attributes5
          - attributes6
    response:
      - sequence: 1
        attributes:
          - attributes7
          - attributes8
```

**Content of application-xyz.yml**

```
authentication:
  name: name
  type: type
  payload:
    request:
      - sequence: 1
        attributes:
          - attributes9
          - attributes10
    response:
      - sequence: 1
        attributes:
          - attributes11
          - attributes12

operations:
  name: name
  type: type
  payload:
    request:
      - sequence: 1
        attributes:
          - attributes13
          - attributes14
    response:
      - sequence: 1
        attributes:
          - attributes15
          - attributes16
```

**Content of ApplicationConfig.java**

```
public interface ApplicationConfig {
    public Authentication getAuthentication();

    public void setAuthentication(Authentication authentication);

    public Operations getOperations();

    public void setOperations(Operations operations);
}
```

**Content of Authentication.java**

```
public class Authentication {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private Payload payload;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Payload getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }

    public void setPayload(Payload payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }
}
```

**Content of Operations.java**

```
public class Operations {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private Payload payload;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Payload getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }

    public void setPayload(Payload payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }
}
```

**Content of Payload.java**

```
public class Payload {
    private List<RequestPayload> request;
    private List<ResponsePayload> response;

    public List<RequestPayload> getRequest() {
        return request;
    }

    public void setRequest(List<RequestPayload> request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    public List<ResponsePayload> getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(List<ResponsePayload> response) {
        this.response = response;
    }
}
```

**Content of RequestPayload.java**

```
public class RequestPayload {
    private String sequece;
    private List<String> attributes;

    public String getSequece() {
        return sequece;
    }

    public void setSequece(String sequece) {
        this.sequece = sequece;
    }

    public List<String> getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }

    public void setAttributes(List<String> attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }
}
```

**Content of ResponsePayload.java**

```
public class ResponsePayload {
    private String sequece;
    private List<String> attributes;

    public String getSequece() {
        return sequece;
    }

    public void setSequece(String sequece) {
        this.sequece = sequece;
    }

    public List<String> getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }

    public void setAttributes(List<String> attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }
}
```

**Content of ApplicationAbcConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource("classpath:application-abc.yml")
public class ApplicationAbcConfig implements ApplicationConfig, PropertySourceFactory {
    private Authentication authentication;
    private Operations operations;

    @Override
    public Authentication getAuthentication() {
        return authentication;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAuthentication(Authentication authentication) {
        this.authentication = authentication;
    }

    @Override
    public Operations getOperations() {
        return operations;
    }

    @Override
    public void setOperations(Operations operations) {
        this.operations = operations;
    }

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(@Nullable String name, EncodedResource resource) throws IOException {
        Properties propertiesFromYaml = loadYamlIntoProperties(resource);
        String sourceName = name != null ? name : resource.getResource().getFilename();
        return new PropertiesPropertySource(sourceName, propertiesFromYaml);
    }

    private Properties loadYamlIntoProperties(EncodedResource resource) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try {
            YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
            factory.setResources(resource.getResource());
            factory.afterPropertiesSet();
            return factory.getObject();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // for ignoreResourceNotFound
            Throwable cause = e.getCause();
            if (cause instanceof FileNotFoundException)
                throw (FileNotFoundException) e.getCause();
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

**Content of ApplicationXyzConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource("classpath:application-xyz.yml")
public class ApplicationXyzConfig implements ApplicationConfig, PropertySourceFactory {
    private Authentication authentication;
    private Operations operations;

    @Override
    public Authentication getAuthentication() {
        return authentication;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAuthentication(Authentication authentication) {
        this.authentication = authentication;
    }

    @Override
    public Operations getOperations() {
        return operations;
    }

    @Override
    public void setOperations(Operations operations) {
        this.operations = operations;
    }

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(@Nullable String name, EncodedResource resource) throws IOException {
        Properties propertiesFromYaml = loadYamlIntoProperties(resource);
        String sourceName = name != null ? name : resource.getResource().getFilename();
        return new PropertiesPropertySource(sourceName, propertiesFromYaml);
    }

    private Properties loadYamlIntoProperties(EncodedResource resource) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try {
            YamlPropertiesFactoryBean factory = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
            factory.setResources(resource.getResource());
            factory.afterPropertiesSet();
            return factory.getObject();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // for ignoreResourceNotFound
            Throwable cause = e.getCause();
            if (cause instanceof FileNotFoundException)
                throw (FileNotFoundException) e.getCause();
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

**Content of ApplicationFactory.java**

```
@Component
public class ApplicationFactory {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationAbcConfig applicationAbcConfig;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationXyzConfig applicationXyzConfig;

    public ApplicationConfig getApplicationPropertiesConfig(String application) {
        if (application.equalsIgnoreCase("abc")) {
            return applicationAbcConfig;
        } else if (application.equalsIgnoreCase("xyz")) {
            return applicationXyzConfig;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Content of YmlConfigurationSelection.java**

```
public class YmlConfigurationSelection {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationFactory applicationFactory;

    private ApplicationConfig applicationConfig;

    public Object accessingProperties(String application) {
        applicationConfig = applicationFactory.getApplicationPropertiesConfig(application);

        return null;
    }
}
```

**Content of MultipleYmlDemoProject.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@SpringBootConfiguration
@PropertySource(factory = ApplicationAbcConfig.class, value = "classpath:application-abc.yml")
@PropertySource(factory = ApplicationXyzConfig.class, value = "classpath:application-xyz.yml")
public class MultipleYmlDemoProject {

    public class MultipleYmlDemo {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx =
                    SpringApplication.run(YamlPropertysourceApplication.class, args);
            ConfigurableEnvironment env = ctx.getEnvironment();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an old spring application that was attempted to be migrated to spring boot.

Spring boot works natively with yaml files, so if you do the integration in a spring boot way, it will be possible to delete a lot of boilerplate code that you have to maintain. Also the naming of configurations is problematic: the names `application-<something>.yml` are reserved to be used with spring boot profiles, maybe if you'll rename to `myprops-abc/xyz.yaml` it will behave in a different way, I can't say for sure.

All-in-all I suggest you the following way, which is much better IMO:

1. Both configuration sets must be loaded into one configuration, so create a configuration properties file that denotes this one configuration:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prexix="security")
public class SecurityConfigProperties {

    private SecurityRealm abc;
    private SecurityRealm xyz;

    // getters, setters
}

public class SecurityRealm {
    private Authentication autentication;
    private Operations operations;
    // getters setters 
}

public class Authentication {...}
private class Operations {...}
```

2. Now place all the content from abc and xyz yaml into one file `application.yaml` and give a 'security' prefix:

```
security:
   abc:   // note, this 'abc' matches the field name of the configuration
     authentication: 
        ...
     operations:
        ....
   xyz:
     authentication: 
        ...
     operations:
        ....
```

3. OK,  everything is mapped, create the configuration like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SecurityConfigProperties.class)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityBeanForABC(SecurityConfigProperties config) {
      return new SecurityBeanForABC(config.getAbc().getAuthentication(), config.getAbc().getOperations());
    } 

    ... the same for XYZ
}
```

Note that with this approach you only maintain a configuration mapping in java objects and there is no code for loading / resolving properties) - everything is done by spring boot automatically. If you configure a special annotation processor and have a descent IDE you can get even auto-completion facilities for those yaml properties but its out of scope for this question. The point is that doing things in a way directly supported by spring boot has many advantages :)

Comment: Actually, I can't write all the content in a single yml file like application.yml because I have so, many different configurations needed for different application which makes overload for a single yml file. So, please If you can help with different files then, it will be helpful for me. For this, I will be very much thankful to you.

Comment: Sure, you can do that. Create different files like you did before: application-abc.yml, application-xyz.yml. One will contain: security:abc:..., another will contain security:xyz:... (the point is that they'll still have different prefixes). Now run the app with --spring.profiles.active=xyz,abc and it will load both files. The configuration will be "merged" into SecurityConfigProperties

Comment: Hi, I want to know something that is extension of this question. As answer of @Mark Bramnik working fine in my case but In want something changes like I want to read properties 'application-abc.yml' and 'application-xyz.yml' files from outside of application meaning even after deployment of jar file. So, please If someone can help me then it's great pleasure for me.

Comment: Why do you need this? In general in spring boot you can specify a folder with configurations (it doesn't have to be inside the jar) but it will still read all the configuration during the application startup. You can However Define Beans that will use this configurations as @Lazy so that they will be actually initialized only when someone calls them and not directly during the startup.

Comment: I need it because someone else will write the properties and I only need to read all those properties. So, can you explain it with some small example?

Comment: The easy way: configuration change is code hence requires redeploy of configurations. Its also possible to use tools like spring cloud config server that allows dynamic bean reloading upon configuration change without the application restart.